# How to Update image in react native

Tags: image, react-native

I was trying to update the user profile but the profile picture only changes ones.To change it each time i had to change the image name each time how to solve it.I have tried to send the request in post method but my api does not support post.I will post my code below.Could some one help me and Thanks in advance.

```
class ProfileEdit extends Component {

  state = {
    username: '',
    email: '',
    about: '',
    userInfo: '',
    avatarSource: null,
    showAlert: false,
    showCancelButton: false,
    showConfirmButton: false,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.selectPhotoTapped = this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this);
  }

  hideAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: false
    });
  };

  selectPhotoTapped() {
    const options = {
      quality: 1.0,
      maxWidth: 500,
      maxHeight: 500,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
      },
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri }
        this.setState({
          avatarSource: source,
        });
        this.upLoadImage(response.uri);
      }
    });
  }

  upLoadImage = async (image_uri) => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    //alert(value)
    var url = 'http://www.dev.beta.duklr.com:8000/api/v2/profile/';
    var b_url = url + value + '/';

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('photo', { type: 'image/jpg', uri: image_uri, name: 'profile_image1.jpg' });
    data.append('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
    fetch(b_url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: data
    }).then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        // alert("response" + JSON.stringify(res)); 
      })
      .catch((e) => this.setState({
        showAlert: true,
        message: e,
        showCancelButton: true,
        cancelText: 'close',
      }))
      .done()
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    //alert(value)
    var url = 'http://www.dev.beta.duklr.com:8000/api/v2/profile/';
    var b_url = url + value + '/';

    //alert(value);

    return fetch(b_url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState(
          {
            isLoading: false,
            refreshing: false,
            userInfo: res,
          },
          function () { }
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          showAlert: true,
          message: error,
          showCancelButton: true,
          cancelText: 'close',
        })
      });
  }



  onUpdate = async () => {

    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    var url = 'my_api';
    var b_url = url + value + '/';

    //alert(b_url);

    const { email, about, avatarSource } = this.state;
    //alert(`${email},${about}`);
    fetch(b_url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        about_us: about,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          showAlert: true,
          message: "Saved successfully",
          showCancelButton: true,
          cancelText: 'close',
        })
        // this.setState({
        //   dataSource: responseJson.promptmsg,
        // })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
          showAlert: true,
          message: error,
          showCancelButton: true,
          cancelText: 'close',
        })
      });
  }
  catch(errors) {
    this.setState({
      showAlert: true,
      message: errors,
      showCancelButton: true,
      cancelText: 'close',
    });
  }

  render() {
    const value_email = this.state.userInfo.email;
    const value_about = this.state.userInfo.about_us;
    return (
      <View style={styles.continer}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', padding: 20 }}>
            <Avatar
              source={this.state.avatarSource}
              size="xlarge"
              // showEditButton
              onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.textContiner}>
            {/* <TextField
              label='User Name'
              title={this.state.userInfo.name}
              value={this.state.username}
              onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
            /> */}
            <TextField
              label='Email Id'
              placeholder={value_email}
              //value={value_email}
              onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
            />
            <TextField
              label='About'
              //value={value_about}
              placeholder={value_about}
              onChangeText={(about) => this.setState({ about })}
            />
            <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
              <Button
                title="Save"
                onPress={this.onUpdate.bind(this)}>
              </Button>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <AwesomeAlert
          show={this.state.showAlert}
          showProgress={false}
          title="Hello There"
          message={this.state.message}
          closeOnTouchOutside={true}
          closeOnHardwareBackPress={true}
          showCancelButton={this.state.showCancelButton}
          showConfirmButton={this.state.showConfirmButton}
          cancelText={this.state.cancelText}
          confirmText={this.state.confirmText}
          confirmButtonColor="#DD6B55"
          onCancelPressed={() => {
            this.hideAlert();
          }}
          onConfirmPressed={() => {
            this.hideAlert();
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default ProfileEdit;
```

Comment: What's FormData() ?

Comment: followed tutorial it shows this method to upload image.Here sending the data as the formData

Answer (score 0):

Is `Avatar` based on React Native's `Image`? To my experience, the `Image` component shipped with React Native is very buggy. Indeed, reloading issue is one of them. I often use [FastImage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) as replacement for `Image`.

Comment: the avatar is a react native elements components.It displays fine but i can update the image only once.